# Split 2 dates into 2 row isq

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to  split holiday between 2 month into 2 row in sql for example :

```
EmpId      StartDate      EndDate     TotalDays
1          2017/5/25     2017/6/10      16
```

I need to split it into 2 row like the following :

```
EmpId      StartDate      EndDate     TotalDays
1          2017/5/25     2017/5/31      6
1          2017/6/1      2017/6/10      10
```

Thanks you

Comment: "update row where.." and "insert.." together may be? (just a work around)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming holidays only have one month split (as in your example):

```
select empid, startdate,
       (case when eomonth(startdate) < enddate then eomonth(startdate) else enddate end) as enddate
from t
union all
select empid, dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(startdate)), enddate
from t
where eomonth(startdate) < enddate;
```

Well, that doesn't give `TotalDays`, but you can do that using a subquery and `datediff()`.

Comment: I use the statement as follow
select id, name,Datestart,DateEnd ,
       (case when eomonth(Datestart) < DateEnd then eomonth(Datestart) else DateEnd end) as enddate
from holday 
union all
select id, dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(Datestart)), DateEnd
from holday
where eomonth(Datestart) < DateEnd


and I got the following err:

Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @AymanQadah . . . There is no `name` in your question and none in my answer.